# Win32 BlockInput doesn't unlock when remoting from xp to xp

Tags: winapi, c#-4.0, remote-desktop

I have a script that invokes the Win32 BlockInput function in C# as follows:

```
public partial class NativeMethods
    {

        /// Return Type: BOOL->int
        ///fBlockIt: BOOL->int
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint =     "BlockInput")]
        [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool BlockInput([System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fBlockIt);

    }

    public static void toggleMouseAndKeyboard(bool flag)
    {
        try
        {
            NativeMethods.BlockInput(flag);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This works fine and dandy whenever I run the script locally, whether Windows 7 or Windows XP. I can also unlock the machine by pressing CTRL + ALT + DEL.

This also will work when I remote from a Windows 7 machine to Windows XP, or Windows 7 to Windows 7. If I highlight the remote desktop window, and press CTRL + ALT + DEL, it will unlock the remote desktop session.

It will even work when I remote from a Windows 7 machine to an XP machine first, and then remote from the XP remote session, to another XP session. I can unlock the second XP session just fine.

However, when I remote from an XP machine to another XP machine, the remote desktop session will NOT unlock after running this script. CTRL + ALT + DEL doesn't work. We have to do a hard restart to get back into the machine, or log someone else in to boot the locked session off.

It seems whenever the local machine that you start remoting on is XP, it will not unlock any remote desktop sessions.
Does anyone know of a way to fix this?